# Get Page Content Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, get, themes, posts

I am using the popular Avada theme in Wordpress. I need to pull content from a specific page similarly to how it can be done to blog posts using "recent posts" element or "blog" element. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I have searched many times using a variety of different keywords to try to learn how to extract specific content from a page (vs. a post). As the answer cannot be found (at least by me) from a search, I figured whatever solutions I am provided by a developer with more expertise would be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not how Stack Overflow works. General questions like this are discouraged. Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Next time I will present a coding-related-only question. Is there no one who has ever needed to do this using this theme?

Comment: I am aware that I could simply add in custom fields, but I'd like to have the original page with little or no edits due to the client's request. I know I can add IDs to Avada's containers and columns. How would I get the content using a specific ID on a container?